# Microsfot Virtual PC 2007 running 3 windows XP VMs on Dual monitors. VM screens freeze on each screen after twenty minutes

Tags: virtualbox, performance, multiple-monitors, virtual-machine

I am currently running three VMs on Microsfot Virtual PC 2007. After about twenty minutes the screen freezes where it is at and will not continue until I move the window the the other monitor. But when it does resume it does where it would as if it runs the entire time.

Also, any way to speed these puppies up? I currently have a Evga Z77 FTW Mobo and a 3570K at 4.2Ghz and 16gb of RAM. I have given each VM 2GB of RAM and they still are sluggish. Any way I can give each their own processor time too? Ideally and I know there would be no quick way to do this, but could I give it alot of cpu time when I have focus on it?

Comment: Windows 7 does not support VPC 2007.
http://www.techrepublic.com/forum/questions/101-320536/virtual-pc-2007-windows-7
You are presumably using VPC 2007 because you do not have hardware visualization support. 
This might explain the sluggishness.

Comment: I got VPC7 because it was the quickest thing at the time. I installed VPC, and then XP on a VM in less than 15 minutes. So my issue is VPC7? Are there any softwares out there that can run the VM's I already have (and faster, better, harder, stronger too)?

Comment: Vpc7 is for Mac. So I'm a little confused. You should try the latest vpc. 2007 is old. The latest is called windows virtual PC. http://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=3702

Comment: In my OP I say "Microsoft Virtual PC 2007", I downloaded it from Microsofts website. I thought you ackronymed it to VPC7, so I did too. I didn't realize VPC7 and Microsoft Virtual PC 2007 were different software. Microsfot Virtual PC 2007 seems to be for windows, it had a .msi installer...